# UPDATE REPLACE funciona no PhpMyAdmin mas não funciona no Workbench

Tags: sql, sql-update, replace

Eu consigo utilizar esse código noPhpmyAdmin:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, 
'src="https://www.meusite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/tipo.gif" alt="Baixar" width="24" height="24"', 
'src="https://www.meusite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/tipo.png" alt="Baixar" width="40" height="40"');
```

Mas quando utilizo no Workbench ele gera erro:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.   0.047 sec
```

Eu desabilitei o o **update safe** mas sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como executar esse REPLACE no Workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem duas maneiras de resolver para uma query:

- Incluir o `where` com o(s) campo(s) que são chave primária, o mais recomendado sempre que possível;
- Usar o comando `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` para desabilitar a validação de SAFE_UPDATES para a sua query. Neste caso, desligue a validação antes de executar o `UPDATE` usando `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0` e depois ligue novamente com `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1`

Lembrando que, isso vale para `UPDATE` e `DELETE`.

Mais informação na documentação do: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates

Comment: Consegui usando um WHERE ;-) Obrigado Ricardo.

Comment: @RobisonLuizFernandes se a resposta foi útil, não esqueça de aceitar :)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a resposta do Ricardo Pontual. Seria possível Usando uma Clausula WHERE, ou usar o Comando comando `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES`.

Utilizei uma Clausula WHERE para permitir que o Banco rode.

```
WHERE ID != 0;
```